# SFML with Eclipse and MinGW is giving an error

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt, sfml

I am trying to use SFML with Eclipse. I have already set up MinGW so that I can write C++ programs in Eclipse. However, when I try to use SFML with it, I get errors.

First I downloaded the MinGW version of SFML [on the SFML download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.0/). Then I unpacked it into `C:/(path to my program)/Debug/SFML`.

Then, I followed the tutorial from http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php. (To see *exactly* what I did, mouse over the space below)

> The next thing I did was right click on my project (in Eclipse) and select "Properties." I went to `C/C++ Build -> Settings`. Under `GCC C++ Compiler -> Preprocessor`, I added `SFML-DYNAMIC` as a defined symbol (`-D`). Then under `GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes`, I added `"SFML\include"` as an include path (`-I`). Finally, under `MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries`, I added `sfml-graphics-d`, `sfml-window-d`, `sfml-audio-d`, and `sfml-system-d` as libraries (`-l`) and `"SFML\lib"` as a library search path (`-L`). I then copied the sample code from the tutorial to the main C++ file.

However, when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> build and then run my program from Eclipse, nothing happens! The program is instantly terminated. When I try to execute `C:/(path to my program)/Debug/SFMLTest.exe`, I get the error

> The program can't start because sfml-graphics-d-2.dll is missing from
>   your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

However, `sfml-graphics-d-2.dll` is indeed in `C:/(path to my program)/Debug/SFML/bin`! How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT** I tried copying everything from `Debug/SFML/bin` into where my `.exe` is, but then when I run it, I get this:

[image: SFMLTest.exe has stopped working]
[image: Close Program]

Answer (score 0):

The `dll`s should be placed in the same directory as your executable file (that is, with SFMLTest.exe), or in your system path (`C:/Windows/System32` from memory). But sometimes, your IDE may execute your program not exactly in the same directory as where it outputs it from compilation (VS does this, at least). Maybe search for this kind of option in the properties and locate correctly your dll.

If you wish to distribute your program, you need to provide the dlls with it, or to compile it statically (this is mentionned in the tutorial from SFML's website).

Comment: @Markus It looks like we didn't. I've never faced this issue so I can't really tell.

Comment: I updated minGW to the latest version (4.8.1) and downloaded SFML 2.1 once again - now it works fine! Unfortunately I can't say what caused this issue

Comment: @Markus good news ! Maybe it had something to do with the exception model. minGW has several versions depending on this, and SFML too. Obviously it needs to be the same.